# Not able to access volatile table in teradata.net mode

Tags: teradata, volatile

I am using Teredata.net to connect to my SQL assistant as i have some issues with my odbc connection.

The problem i am facing is i am able to create a volatile table but when i do a select * it says table doesn't exist. I am not sure if that has anything to do with the connection as i have never used teradata.net connection before. below is my table syntax;

```
 CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE VT
(
COL1 VARCHAR(100)
) 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Can any one help me here.

Regards,
Amit

Comment: Seems your session is closed inbetween queries. Check if *Tools - Options - Query - Disconnect from database when no query is running* is set and uncheck it.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth,
That option is unchecked. I figured out that i have to run the entire query as a single transaction in order to work it out. That was not the case when i used odbc connection.

Comment: No, there must be something else. I had a case when SQL Assistant didn't notice that a session was finished and reconnected every time. Run multiple `SELECT SESSION;` and check if the number changes. Then try a restart of SQLA.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth,
I checked with multiple SELECT SESSION; I got different numbers each time. Is that fine? Should i restart sqla ?

Comment: Of course that's not fine. Try restarting SQLA.

Comment: Yes, that's worked ..Thanks a lot dnoeth.. u are awesome!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if you specify **ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS**
2. Check if you get the same number by **select session**;
3. **Restart** the Teradata SQL assistant - it helped me